# How to display month in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to convert month number to month name.

The result that i get now is

```
Month  
1,2,3
```

The output i need is

```
Month
Jan, Feb, March
```

I try if else but not working

Answer (score 1):

Make new formula field `formula_month`

[image]

[image]

And write this formula in it

```
MonthName({your_field_name})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it show an error a number is required here {your_field_name} and when i run through app nothing happens